# Percentage is not properly working in css

Tags: css

when I use percentage value for width and height in css its not working properly...
can some one explain me clearly how to give percentage values for css attributes and how does it works?
thank u in advance

This is my css

```
    body 
{
    width:1440px;
    height:900px;

}
div.head
{
    background-image:url(Head.png);
    background-position:top center;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
}
div.main
{
    background-color:White;
    width:100%;
    height:50%
}
div.foot
{
    background-color:White;
    width:100%;
    height:50%
}
```

HTML generated on browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Main
</title><link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/StyleSheet1.css" />
    <script type="text/jscript" src="Js/JScript1.js"></script>


</head>
<body >
    <form method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTY1NDU2MTA1MmRkKXI1tlT7ICPHcASdjP2BI5BEiw8ccKKJsW4NczkZMbs=" />

</div>

    <div id="header" class="head">
    Menu comes here
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="main">

Body comes here

    </div>
     <div id="footer" class="foot">
   footer comes here
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of whats not working, please?

Comment: a complete example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Percentages are relative to the parent element. 50% will make it half of the width or height of the parent and not the entire page. Is this where your problem occurs? If not, we need some code.

Answer (score 5):

I guarantee you the percentages are "working". They're just not doing what you *expect*.

What `height: 50%` means is that the element's height will be half the height of the box containing it. So, your problem is likely that the containing element is not tall enough (if your styled element is too short) or too tall (if your styled element is higher than expected).

You should use a tool like Chrome's Developer Tools to inspect the sizings of the elements on your page and see which one doesn't match your assumptions, then use CSS to correct the issue.

Comment: Thank you yes its working but i din't get what I expected.....................  I need the width and height of the classes(head,main,foot) based on the width and height of the body tag????????

Comment: @user1202023 Show us your HTML

Comment: <body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="header" class="head">
    Menu comes here
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
     <div id="footer" class="foot">
   footer comes here
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

Comment: @user1202023 So you have three `div`s inside your `body`. One of them is height 25%, one is height 50%, and the last is height 50%. That adds up to 125%. How exactly do you expect this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should be:

```
body 
{
    width:1440px;
    height:900px;

}
div.head
{
    background-image:url(Head.png);
    background-position:top center;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
}
div.main
{
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}
div.foot
{
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}
```

I have added semicolons and changed `White` to `white`.

The percentages should be *working* but I don't think you know what it does.

From Borealid's answer:

> What `height: 50%` means is that the element's height will be half the height of the box containing it. So, your problem is likely that the containing element is not tall enough (if your styled element is too short) or too tall (if your styled element is higher than expected).

Comment: I need the width and height of the classes(head,main,foot) based on the width and height of the body tag????????

Comment: @user1202023 how much percentage?

Comment: @user1202023 That is what percentages are for!

Comment: For me its not working that way i dono wat mistake i have done  see the scree shot of the output http://www.flickr.com/photos/76990534@N08/?saved=1

Comment: @user1202023 change the height of the `<div>`s